# ToLocalTime not working in Generic conversion

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Static Method for displaying Property Values on a table. Currently I'm not able to get the DateTime Property Values to convert to Local. If I specify them outside the method explicitly on the object (as non generic) I can convert them fine. When I specify them through this method or elsewhere using generics it fails to convert. I'd like to know why and preferably how to fix it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to Try and get a value of a property by the <para />
/// property's name and return it formatted as a string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj">Object with the property</param>
/// <param name="name">Property's Name</param>
/// <param name="format">Output format if any</param>
public static string GetByNameFormatted(this Object obj, string name, string format = "")
{
  PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
  if (null == prop || !prop.CanWrite) return string.Empty;

  if (prop.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
  {
    DateTime val = (DateTime)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
    DateTime utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(val, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return utc.ToLocalTime().ToString("G");
  }

  if (prop.GetType() == typeof(DateTime?))
  {
    DateTime? val = (DateTime?)prop.GetValue(obj, null);

    if (val != null)
    {
      DateTime utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(val.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
      return utc.ToLocalTime().ToString("G");
    }
  }

  if (prop.GetType() == typeof(decimal) || prop.GetType() == typeof(double))
  {
    decimal val = (decimal)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
    return val.ToString(format);
  }

  return prop.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
}
```

Comment: `it fails to convert` what does it do?

Comment: @Charlieface , It stays as it's original time in UTC. I've tried removing the SpecifyKind method and the result remains as it's original UTC.

Comment: Please give us a [mcve] (preferably as a https://dotnetfiddle.net) showing a `DateTime` value with `Kind`, that you can convert outside this function but not inside

Comment: @Charlieface https://dotnetfiddle.net/j0FnNc

Comment: `if (prop.GetType()` should be `if (prop.PropertyType`, otherwise you will get `typeof(RuntimeTypeInfo)`

Comment: @Charlieface While I appreciate the response, that seems to have no affect on the outcome.

Comment: @Charlieface Scratch that, it worked but it didn't work in the Fiddle for whatever reason. I appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: DotNetFiddle has time zone set to +0:00